# Convert the following array with index to a string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array output with index as:

```
[{"0":"10:00PM","2":"12:00PM"}]
```

I want to convert this to a string something like:

```
[{"10:00PM","12:00PM"}]
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: `[{"10:00PM","12:00PM"}]` this is not a valid JSON

Comment: Why do you want to convert the original string. Which is a JSON String

Comment: I am unable to convert this array.I tried to use implode,but no luck.I just want to convert it to a string.

Comment: Did you try `$arr = json_decode($var_containing_the_JSONString);`

Comment: so to be clear, you want to convert a valid json string to a string that kinda looks like it but aint valid json ?

Comment: You say you have an array but it looks like a string. Can you add the output of a `var_dump()` of your variable to the question? And what does "something like" mean exactly?

Comment: actually i want without the index 0,1,2....

Comment: var dump leads to the same array

Comment: If you were to tell us EXACTLY what you want to do with the STRING we could probably be more help

Comment: current the json has the indexes ryt like 0,1,2 i don't want that.Thats it.

Comment: But you are asking for `[{"10:00PM","12:00PM"}]` which makes no sense, Its not valid JSON and it's not much sense as a string either

Comment: Not exactly,that something similar withou the indexes.

Comment: `$o=json_decode($s);$p='[{'.$o[0]->{0}.','.$o[0]->{2}.'}]';` if `$s` is your original JSON, that'll do what you want ... not sure I see the point but OK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **preg_replace** to replace string for following output.

```
$json = '[{"0":"10:00PM","2":"12:00PM"}]';
$result = preg_replace("/\"\d\"\:/","",$json);
echo $result;
```

Output

```
[{"10:00PM","12:00PM"}]
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/aEn5M)

Know more about [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: This shows error : Array to string conversion

In laravel  framework

Comment: @gaan10 first convert your array/object to json string by using **$json = json_encode($data) **

$data is here array/object which contain your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just push your value into an array.

```
$data = array();
array_push($data,"10:00PM");
array_push($data,"12:00PM");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:

```
[{"10:00PM","12:00PM"}]
```

Comment: You *won't* get that output, because that output is **not** a valid JSON; what you get is `["10:00PM","12:00PM"]` (note the lack of curly braces).